# How to read/get the *Publish Version* of an Assembly file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, version, .net-assembly

In VS2017, in the Post-build event, I include a Powershell script:

```
powershell "start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '$(ProjectDir)Resources\PostBuild.ps1',
'$(ProjectDir)', '$(TargetDir)', '$(ConfigurationName)', '$(SolutionName)'"
```

In that PS script I read the produced assembly to get the *Publish Version*:

```
$ass = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($file) 

# This gets the AssemblyVersion:
$v = $ass.GetName().Version
$version = [string]::Format("{0}.{1:00}.{2:00}.{3}",$v.Major, $v.Minor, $v.Build, $v.Revision)
Write-Host $version

# This gets the ProductVersion and the FileVersion:
$FVI = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($file)
Write-Host $FVI
```

However, the sample PS code above gets me the *Assembly Version*, the *Product Version* and the *File Version* but I could not find a way to obtain the ***Publish Version***. Anyone can tell me how to do that?
I found lots of examples for the *Assembly Version* but not one example for the *Publish Version*.
Thanks.
*Answers for Powershell (rather than, say, C#) appreciated.*

Comment: Near as I can tell that version is an attribute of a Click-Once deployment, rather than the Assembly itself.  There are a number of examples retrieving the version from within the running code, but I don't see anything obvious about retrieving them externally.

Comment: You may have something there. It seems to be embedded in the App.application file produced by the deployment process. Perhaps it's not in the assembly. IF it's ONLY in the App.application file anyone knows how to extract the information?